# bind properties to a listview

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp

I have a Weather VM, that get my city and country code perfectly, but I am trying to bind the rest of my data to XAML.
All my data is store in the array, and for some reason, when I loop, the variable i, does not increment and the app crash.

I also have the problem of the icon, I have a list, that is the itemsource of my Listview, but the Icon is on another array

I tried to loop, and assign each variable, and the loop always crash

```
            var splitedData = cityData.Split(",");
            var city = splitedData[0];
            var conutryCode = splitedData[1];

            var data = await WeatherAPI.GetWeatherDataAsync(city, conutryCode);
            if (data != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < data.list.Count; i++) {
                    rootObject.list[i].dt_txt = data.list[i].dt_txt;
                    rootObject.list[i].main.temp_max = data.list[i].main.temp_max;
                    rootObject.list[i].main.temp_min = data.list[i].main.temp_min;
                    rootObject.list[i].weather[i].icon
                }
            }
        }
```

xaml listView

```
                  Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding rootObject.list}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RelativePanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="dateTB"
                                   Text="{Binding dt_txt}"
                                   RelativePanel.RightOf="iconTB"
                                   RelativePanel.AlignTopWith="iconTB" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="highTB"
                                   Text="{Binding main.temp_max}"
                                   RelativePanel.RightOf="iconTB"
                                   RelativePanel.Below="dateTB"
                                   FontSize="10" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="lowTB"
                                   RelativePanel.RightOf="highTB"
                                   RelativePanel.Below="dateTB"
                                   FontSize="10"
                                   Text="{Binding main.temp_min}"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        <Image x:Name="iconTB"
                               Source="{}"
                               Height="30"
                               Width="30"
                              />
                    </RelativePanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
```

I expect the Dates to appear, the High to appear and the low to appear.

Also I have don't have a clue of how to bind the icon, becouse the icon is in Weather, and not the RootObject list, that is the itemsource of my list

Comment: the Icon is store on `rootObject.list[i].weather[i].icon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in my side and find something might be the reason. The problem might be that you didn't create instances for main object or weather list or day list. So you are assigning values to null and then it gives error.

I changed it a little bit, you can try in your side.(I still can't use `MapLocator.GetCityData();` so I haven't tried this with real data.)

```
    public class RootObject : Notify
{
    private List<Day> _list;
    public List<Day> list
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _list)
            {
                _list = value;
                onPropertyChanged("list");
            }
        }
    }
    public RootObject()
    {
        //I added five objects for test. In real scenario, the count depends on the data number you get
        list = new List<Day>();
        list.Add(new Day());
        list.Add(new Day());
        list.Add(new Day());
        list.Add(new Day());
        list.Add(new Day());
    }
}

public class Day : Notify
{
    private Main _main;
    public Main main
    {
        get { return _main; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _main)
            {
                _main = value;
                onPropertyChanged("main");
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Weather> _weather;
    public List<Weather> weather
    {
        get { return _weather; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _weather)
            {
                _weather = value;
                onPropertyChanged("weather");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _dt_txt;
    public string dt_txt
    {
        get { return _dt_txt; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _dt_txt)
            {
                _dt_txt = value;
                onPropertyChanged("dt_txt");
            }
        }
    }
    public Day()
    {
        main = new Main();
        //I added five objects for test. In real scenario, the count depends on the data number you get
        weather = new List<Weather>();
        weather.Add(new Weather());
        weather.Add(new Weather());
        weather.Add(new Weather());
        weather.Add(new Weather());
        weather.Add(new Weather());
    }

}
```

For local test, I just added 5 objects. In your real scenario, you need to check the count of data from bingmap.

Comment: The ting is that a ma using MVVM and the itemsource for my List is ```rootObject.list``` and I don't know if it should be the DataContext instead, I have it on github, if you can take a look https://github.com/eduardoagr/MVVM_Excersice. why the way do you kkow what is a semi-alternating substring

Comment: I tried your sample.  I always get exception when calling `MapLocator.GetCityData()`.  If I'm using data that created locally like what I did in my reply, all the data could show correctly. I suspect the problem is related to the data that get from locationmanager.

Comment: When I run the app, I get back My current location, so i am only trying to retrieve the data. Maybe instead of having ```itemsouce = Binding rootObject.list``` I shoud use ```datacontext = Binding rootObject.list``` ? by the day can you define a for loop in xaml to get the icon

Comment: Maybe the exception in the ```MapLocator.GetCityData()``` is becouse the bingMap key is associated to my account?

Comment: Maybe I haven't said it clearly. All the sample code works correctly if I don't use the `MapLocator.GetCityData()` to get data. Just create data locally and the listview could show all the bindings without changing anything. That's why I think the data or the data model will be the reason. Why not share me the data model for all the class you used?

Comment: Thank you for all the help, but is strange hat the ```MapLocator.GetCityData()``` dosent work for you. For me I can see my location on the xaml

Comment: I find something might be the reason after using your code. You said that in the loop which you used to give value to the data model will crash. The problem might be that you haven't created the main object instance, weather list instance, day list instance when you wants to assign value to their properties. I'll update my answer and you might check that.